# Process a string with gnuplot to remove a specific character

Tags: gnuplot

I apologize if this question has an obvious solution, but for the life of me I can't seem to get my gnuplot script to run if I try to use an `if`-`else if`-`else` syntax, I have to nest the `if`-`else`'s as follows (I'm using version 4.6).

What I'm trying to do is loop over, say, 99 files and plot the vectorfields from the data therein, then save those plots with names like 'something001.png' all the way to 'something099.png', i.e. there's one less `0'. Looking through the documentation, however, I haven't yet come across something that will do this (so I've resorted to some basic if's and else's).

```
#! /usr/bin/gnuplot
# plot data in vectorfields to same directory

factor=0.05
set term png
# Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, && Ymax are passed as command line args
set xrange [Xmin:Xmax]
set yrange [Ymin:Ymax]

do for [i=1:numImages] {
    # Control output formatting (surely there's a shortcut for this?)
    if (i < 10) {
        set output "vectors/plot00".i.".png"
    } else {
        # no else-if syntax (that I can find)?
        if (i < 100) {
            set output "vectors/plot0".i.".png"
        } else {
            set output "vectors/plot".i.".png"
        }
    }
}
```

Does there exist a simpler syntax for doing this kind of thing?

Comment: so you want to have something like `printf("%d3d", fileNum)`? (Best to show desired output VS current output. Good luck.

Comment: `set output sprintf("vectors/plot%03d.png", i)`

Comment: @Christoph that's exactly what I was looking for.